# How to improve regex so it can match email format for google script email scraper?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make an email scraper that can read your emails and put transactions into a google sheet for easy budgeting.

The format of the email is as such:

```
This is an Alert to help you manage your credit card account ending in 0000.

As you requested, we are notifying you of any charges over the amount of ($USD) 0.01, as specified in your Alert settings. A charge of ($USD) 44.44 at UBER * EATS PENDIN has been authorized on Apr 34, 2073 at 2:27 PM ET.

Do not reply to this Alert.

If you have questions, please call the number on the back of your credit card, or send a secure message from your Inbox on www.bank.com.

To see all of the Alerts available to you, or to manage your Alert settings, please log on to www.bank.com.
```

I'm trying to capture just the price (44.44), the company (Uber Eats), the date (Apr 34, 2073) and the time (2:27 PM ET).

I have this as my regex:

```
/A charge of\s\W+\w+\W+\s(.+?(?=at))\w+\s(.+?(?=has))\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s(.+?(?=at))\w+\s(.+?(?=ET))/g
```

however it's no longer working despite it matching in regex101.

Any thoughts on how I can get it to match in google scripts so I can scrape the emails? Everything else works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few notes about the pattern that you tried

- You can omit the lookahead assertions `(?=` inside the capture groups and instead make the text part of the match.
- The assertion `(?=ET)` at the end will make `ET` not part of the group.
- You might consider making the date part a bit more specific (or at least verify that part as a valid date later on) as accepting a date like `Apr 34, 2073` the customer might never get his order

You might simplify the pattern to

```
\bA\s+charge\s+of\s+\D*\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+at\s+(\S.*?)\s+has\s+been\s+authorized\s+on\s+(\S.*?)\s+at\s+([^.]+)\.
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bA\s+charge\s+of\s+\D*\b` Match `A charge of`  followed by any char except a digit between word boundaries to prevent a partial match
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\s+at\s+` Match `at` between whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 2** Match a non whitespace char followed by as last chars as possible
- `\s+has\s+been\s+authorized\s+on\s+` Match `has been authorized on`
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 3** Match a non whitespace char followed by as last chars as possible
- `\s+at\s+` Match `at` between whitespace chars
- `([^.]+)` Capture **group 4** Match 1+ chars other than a `.`
- `\.` Match a `.`

If there can be more matches, you can use the `/g` flag and loop the results for all the groups.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/diN8RE/1)

```js
const regex = /\bA charge of \D*\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) at (\S.*?) has been authorized on (\S.*?) at ([^.]+)\./g;
const str = `This is an Alert to help you manage your credit card account ending in 0000.

As you requested, we are notifying you of any charges over the amount of (\$USD) 0.01, as specified in your Alert settings. A charge of (\$USD) 44.44 at UBER * EATS PENDIN has been authorized on Apr 34, 2073 at 2:27 PM ET.

Do not reply to this Alert.

If you have questions, please call the number on the back of your credit card, or send a secure message from your Inbox on www.bank.com.

To see all of the Alerts available to you, or to manage your Alert settings, please log on to www.bank.com.`;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  m.forEach((match, i) => {
    if (i > 0) console.log(match);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Using PCRE capabilities here, this will create 3 capturing groups from which you could get the values as per your need.

```
^(?:As you requested.*\$USD\)\s+)(\d+\.\d+)\s+[\w]+\s+([^ ]*).*?authorized on(.*)\.$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/KocRMe/2)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^(?:                           ##Matching from starting of value, starting a non-capturing group.
As you requested.*\$USD\)\s+   ##Matching string As you requested. till $USD) spaces here.
)                              ##Closing non-capturing group here.
(\d+\.\d+)                     ##1st capturing group has digits DOT digits here.
\s+[\w]+\s+                    ##Matching spaces word characters spaces here.
([^ ]*)                        ##2nd capturing group matches till any spaces(basically Uber value will come here).
.*?authorized on               ##Matching everything till authorized on here.
(.*)\.$                        ##Matching everything till last dot comes of the line, time and date basically.
```

Comment: Or use `^(?:As you requested.*\$USD\)\s+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+[\w]+\s+([^ ]*).*?authorized on(.*)\.$` to cover integer and float both values with regex.

Answer (score 5):

Your Regex looks good to me, the only problem I see, you are using `global` with that you'll not get the matched groups. If you remove it it'll work fine. Please refer [MDN RegEx.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value)

You could try like this with named groups.

```js
const string =`A charge of ($USD) 44.44 at UBER * EATS PENDIN has been authorized on Apr 34, 2073 at 2:27 PM ET.`;
const regEx = /^A charge of\s\((?<currency>.+)\)\s(?<amount>\d+\.?\d+) at (?<company>.+) has been authorized on (?<date>.+) at (?<time>.+)\.$/;

console.log(string.match(regEx).groups)
```

Please check for browser support before using **Named capture groups**, [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_named_capture_groups).